# Behave `before_scenario` hook does not remember initialized variable value

Tags: python, cucumber, bdd, python-behave

I am using [behave](https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fixtures.html) fixtures to create a counter during test run. I initialize the counter in `before_all` hook, and later increment it in `before_scenario` every time a scenario is running.

I thought `before_all` runs once during the entire test, and if a variable is added to the context it is available for later.

Here I am initializing `context.i = 0` in `before_all`, but in `before_scenario` every time a scenario is run, the value of `context.i` is again set to 0.

**environment.py**

```
def before_all(context):
    context.i = 0

def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.i = context.i + 1
```

I want to increment `i` with every run. But it is always set to `1`.

Answer (score 2):

For those having a similar purpose. You can use a dict attribute and store the variables as keys. This way, every time a new stack is added to the frame the context dict is preserved.

```
def before_all(context):
    context.mydata = {}
    context.i = 0 // will be overridden
    context.mydata['i'] = 1 // will be preserved


def before_scenario(context, scenario):
    context.mydata['i'] += 1
    context.i += 1
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Context user variables, defined in before_scenario accessible only in scenario lifycycle. When runner start next scenario, `context.i` defined in last scenario is no longer exist, so it uses variable, defined in before_all hook.
I guess you can't change context user variable defined in before_all hook.